# How do I create explicit intents for all my activities in a separate class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I have a button that brings down a layout filled with pages for other activities, when i touch on any of them, it jumps to it via explicit intents:

[image: kkkkk]

I can create multiple onClick methods on every page like this:

```
public void goToPage3(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Page2.this , Page3.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
public void goToPage5(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Page2.this , Page5.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}// and so on up to page20
```

But then it will take so much to code it up, instead i want to create separate class that creates intents from each activity on demand.

```
public class MenuDetails{

public Intent createIntent(Context from, Class to){
    return new Intent(from,to);
 //Context from is unknown
}
```

}
the problem is that i can't figure out how to "know" what current context it was called from

Comment: Try using this getBaseContext()  as a parameter when you are calling createIntent() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple call this like:

```
new MenuDetails().createIntent(this, SecondActivity.class);
```

Where 'this' is the context of that activity from where you call this function.

Comment: yes, but this has to be in every activity, i have 26 activities, and each has this content part

Comment: Yes you have to right it in all your activities, your approach is right rather than duplicating the 3,4 lines of code, you are just calling the function with the difference of only 2nd parameter.
The 1st parameter i.e. the context ('this') will remain the same for all the function calls.

Comment: So late for you but why don't you make an Override of AppCompatActivity ? Extend a class of it and add that method of yours and then in your 26 activities extend from your class.